# Meteor: 3 roles can access each other's routes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In my Meteor app, I have three roles: a guest (just a visitor to the website), a customer (a registered user) and an admin user (the superuser that manages the customers).

I have defined some routes as follows:

- For the guests: /home, /about
- For the customers: /customer/dashboard, /customer/documents, ...
- For the admin: /admin/dashboard, /admin/manage

I have a router file where I have the following:

```
Iron.Router.hooks.requireCustomer = function () {
  if (!Meteor.user() && !Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'customer')) {
    //if it's a user and the user has a role 'customer'
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render('this.loadingTemplate');
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Iron.Router.hooks.requireAdmin = function () {
   if (!Meteor.user() && !Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin')) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render('this.loadingTemplate');
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction('requireCustomer', {except: ['home', 'about']});
Router.onBeforeAction('requireAdmin', {only: ['adminDashboard']});
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: ['documentIndex','documentNew', 'documentIndex', 'documentShow', 'documentEdit']});
```

When I access /customer/dashboard or /admin/dashboard when not logged in, everything is OK (I get access denied page). However, when I log in as a customer, I can access /admin/dashboard. Obviously, this should never be the case. Also when logged in as 'admin', I can access /customer/dashboard and that should also not be the case. I thought my requireCustomer and requireAdmin hooks would cover for that, but that's not the case it seems. Any ideas?

Note: Am using alanning:roles

Comment: Feels like your `except` condition for `requireCustomer` says that the customer role is required for every route except `home` and `about` which means you'd have to be a customer to access `adminDashboard` as well as an admin?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The funny thing is that when I add 'adminDashboard' to the except list, I still don't get an access denied. The reasoning is that the customer role is not needed for 'adminDashboard'. So adding that to the except clause does not seem to be the solution